# Keras backend switch combined with tf.where not working as intended

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom loss function where I want to change values from a one-hot based encoding to values in a certain range to calculate an IOU.

Part of this code is to look at where I have a one in a tensor that has zeros otherwise. For this I am using tf.where which returns me the location. I have a vector of shape [batch_size,S1,S2,12] where I only care for the last dimension, thats why I take [...,2] of tf.where.

Now it often happens that my prediction is all zeros because I have background events without any values in them and also my network will predict an all zero vector every now and then. This means tf.where will return an empty tensor.
Thats why I want to use K.switch to check if the tensor is empty, because if it is I would like to have zeros returned.

The problem is now that K.switch expects the shape of the then else options to have the same shape but I need my output to have shape [batch_size,S1,S2,1]. I have tried different things but I cant get this to work.
I need to get zeros of shape [batch_size,S1,S2,1] or I need where_box1 to have [batch_size,S1,S2,1] with floats.

The way its implemented now, K.switch returns an empty vector of zeros when where_box1_temp is empty, which is not what I want.
When I use tf.zeros([batch_size,S1,S2,1]) instead it will complain that the conditions are of different shape when where_box1_temp is empty....

```
where_box1_temp = tf.where(y_pred[...,C+1:C+13])[...,2]

where_box1 = K.switch(tf.equal(tf.size(where_box1_temp),0) , 
                          tf.zeros_like(where_box1_temp) , where_box1_temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround, maybe this is helpful for someone else:

```
where_box1_temp = tf.where(y_pred[...,C+1:C+13],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],0)

where_box1 = tf.reshape(K.sum(where_box1_temp,axis=3),[batch_size,5,5])
```

This allows me to have a tensor of my desired shape where all background/zero prediction values are 0 without having to use k.switch and having trouble with any empty dimensions or something like that.